# Unable to render simple react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following this beginner React tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithMosh

Have installed React and Babel and have React working on http://localhost:3000/ (default screen)

But when I try to change the default render to a Counter it does not render, my code seem to be identical to the tutorial, any help appreciated.

No errors showing on debug console.

Have two files index.js and counter.jsx

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App"
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Counter from './components/counter';

ReactDom.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById("root"));
registerServiceWorker();
```

counter.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    render() { 
        return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
    }
}
 
export default Counter;
```

Comment: You using any module blunder like webpack?

Comment: Well, for sure you have to change `ReactDom` to `ReactDOM` as you imported it with this name. Then let us know if you get other errors. :)

Comment: Thanks to codemonkey and Emanuele for your help. I figured out I made a stupid mistake in mixing up which project I was updating. All working ok now.